# Connect Macbook Pro to thunderbolt and a Dell monitor (with HDMI)

Tags: macos

I have a mac book pro (Nov 2011 model) and 2 monitors, a thunderbolt and a DELL with HDMI. Is there a way I can use my laptop with these 2 displays ? Thunderbolt supports daisy chaining, with 2 thunderbolt displays, but can I use a non thunderbolt display and a thunderbolt display to work with together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219?viewlocale=en_US#minimul) a mini-displayport cable must be directly connected to the thunderbolt port on the machine and not daisy chained through another monitor.

Comment: So I connect the mini display port to my laptop and have some kinda splitter which connects to both the thunderbolt and my monitor ?